# unable to specify the reason for error when trying to read from an input file stream

Tags: c++, input, fstream

assuming that the included file uses namespace std and contains the std library facilities .

i have written a program to write points on the coordinate plane to some input file stream and then use that stream to add those points to a `vector<point>` object;
i have written the program that writes to the input file stream and it works well because i could see the points which i added  because my file had a .txt extension namely m.txt
here's my code

```
#include"../dumbheader.h.txt"
struct point {
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    point(int i,int j):x(i),y(j){}
    point(){}
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is, point& p) {    // input format accepted (int,int)
    char ch1, ch2,ch3;
    if (is >> ch1 && ch1 == '(') {
        if (!(is >> p.x))
            error(" an integer expected \n");
        if (!(is >> ch2 && ch2 == ','))
            error(" a ',' is expected ");
        if (!(is >> p.y))
            error(" bad second argument \n");
        if (!(is >> ch3 && ch3 == ')'))
            error(" ) expected \n");
    }
    else error(" ( expected ");
    return is;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const point& p) {

    os <<'(' <<p.x << "," << p.y<<')';
    return os;

}
    vector<point>vp;
    void printv(vector<point>v) {

        for (auto x : v)
            cout << x << endl;

    }
    void end_of_loop(istream& ist, char term, const string& message)
    {
        if (ist.fail()) { // use term as terminator and/or separator
            ist.clear();
            char ch;
            if (ist >> ch && ch == term) return; // all is fine
            error(message);
        }
    }
    int main()try{
        
        vector<point>pp;
        {
            ifstream ifs{ "m.txt" };

            for (point p; ifs >> p;)
                pp.push_back(p);
        
        }
        printv(pp);

        
    }
    catch (runtime_error& e) {
        cout << e.what();
    }
```

i have omitted the code that writes to m.txt lest that i have to repeatedly write the points to the file, however the code works fine and the file has the text: (1,1)(2,2)(3,3)(4,4).
the output of the code:  ( expected
C:\Users\abdua\source\repos\DrillsOnChap10Points\x64\Debug\DrillsOnChap10Points.exe (process 21104) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .
what i don't understand is why i get this message, the file seems good.

i have added a static int to the input function to write how many times it has been called by outputting the integer before error() is called the latter throws a runtime error. the integer is always one past the number of elements in the file , it is as if the input loop tries to read beyond the end of the file.
at this point i'm very confused as to why this is the case; because the input file stream should be closed at the end of the it's associated scope_if i understand correctly.
edit:

i have changed the scope inside main to

```
{
    ifstream ifs{ "m.txt" };
    int i = 1;
    for (point p; ifs >> p&&i<=3;i++)
        pp.push_back(p);

}
```

and the code outputs the three point at the beginning. it seems like the problem is with the fourth read; changing the test for i to i<=4 will cause the same problem.

Comment: Look at this: https://godbolt.org/z/arjrWxcqv - I have to add 15 more lines for getting your code compiled because you have ignored the requirement to post a [mcve]. *assuming that the included file uses namespace std and contains the std library facilities* - very bad assumption.

Comment: So, it is a runtime output, not the code error. [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: it simply means that i use the std::iostream an using namespace std: ,how is this a bad assumption?

Comment: The code as written isn't good at handling an end-of-line character (`\n`)

Comment: @Abdullah, you haven't shown any code that actually calls your >> operator (too many times by the sound of it). Please give adequate information.

Comment: @lastchance it's called in the for loop as a test

Comment: @AbdullahOthman, I see no such statement. The only for loop that I can see uses ```<<```, not ```>>```

Comment: In your edited post: ```ifs >> p&&i<=3```. You tried to read the stream BEFORE testing the value of i. Did you intend that?

Comment: @lastchance i forgot about the order there i did not intend that i reversed the order to i<=4&&ifs>>p and the code outputs all the values ,thanks for your comment i appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:** The stream ends up in fail state when reading `is >> ch1` making it return false, because you have reached the end-of-file (there is no more to read).

When you read a `point` you do this

```cpp
if (is >> ch1 && ch1 == '(') {
 ...
}
else {
  error(" ( expected ");
}
```

When you use the [`>>` operator of the `ifstream` (technically the more general `istream`)](https://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) it returns the stream itself and then you execute the [`bool` operator on `istream`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/), which returns false if the stream is in a [fail-state](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/iostate/) (either `failbit` or `badbit` is set). As mentioned in the [`istream::operator >>` reference](https://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) it may end up in this state, if you attempt to read the current input from the stream into an object but that reading fails (e.g. if the input cannot be parsed to that object type).,

In your code, you assume that you got a wrong character when trying to read the `(` and it fails, but what really happens is that you are trying to read an input into an object when the stream has reached the *end-of-file* (i.e. there is no more to read).
You should have a check for this, either in your for-loop, or in your `point` parsing, where you let it fail when reaching end-of-file:

```cpp
if (is >> ch1 && ch1 == '(') {
 ...
}
else if (is.eof()) {
  return is;
}
else {
  error(" ( expected");
}
```

**Also...**
Please, heed to the advice that the other comments mentioned wrt. how to post your question - you're more likely to get an answer if it's easier to replicate your problem. I couldn't copy-paste your code and run it (i.e. it's not a minimal reproducible example).